# Publish more research papers or advise dissertations?

Tags: research-process, advisor

A faculty should advise students working on dissertations and to publish also. However, publications can come from students working on dissertations, from working alone or from collaborating with others like postdocs. So should faculty advise more students working on their dissertations or work with other researchers? It is clear that faculty should do both of them, but should anyone be given a higher priority?

Comment: The relative value placed on the various components of an academic job is one of the main things that differentiates the world's tens of thousands of academic institutions from each other.  Even within one department different faculty members may set different priorities; having done so, they may be equally successful or they may not, and it is not always easy to predict how things will work out in individual cases.  How are we supposed to answer this question in general?  What kind of answer do you have in mind?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I agree with you that it is hard to generalize. However, I would say that universities may care more on publications than dissertations, if that would increase their ranking for example.

Comment: Yes, they certainly *may*.  Some institutions and departments do not have graduate programs, so they obviously care more about publications than the program that they don't have.  And in some departments, advising graduate students is one of the most important things that a faculty member can do, such that a faculty member who arrived and didn't do enough of that would bring the department life to a screeching halt.  Again, what kind of general answer do you expect?  Also, why do you ask: are you a new faculty member trying to decide how to spend your time?

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic because "The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a **certain person’s preferences**, **a given institution’s regulations**, **the exact contents of your work or your personal values**."

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I am teaching so I would like to know who things work

Comment: Despite some faults, I think this is a decent-enough question and very relevant to those new faculty wanting to get a general sense of the tradeoffs involved between publishing and advising. Since an answer depends on the field/local norms, then answerers can simply state that information. Voting to reopen (an edit is probably in order, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is largely a false dichotomy. For instance, there's no reason a paper written by one of your students can't involve collaborators at your institution or from other institutions as well.

So long as your students are publishing, and you're establishing a network, I wouldn't worry about trying to prioritize one over the other, *unless* your institution's promotion and tenure regulations have something specific to say in the matter.

Comment: Although I find the question difficult to answer in general, I actually think there's some truth to the dichotomy.  In my field (mathematics), advising students (i) need not lead to publications at all, (ii) even if it does then it is far from guaranteed that I will be a coauthor, and (iii) even if I am such collaborations generally have a different tenor from collaborations with post-PhD mathematicians.  I think it is accurate to say that I could collaborate more with others if I didn't advise students, so: yes, there is a tradeoff, and my actions are strongly informed by own values.